# How to draw on System::Drawing::Graphics by a Timer Tick

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have `Graphics^ g` created on a PictureBox. I can draw on it inside events like `MyForm_Load`, `Button_Click`, but not in `Timer_Tick`. It doesn't draw anything:

```
System::Void timer1_Tick(...) {
    g->Clear(Color::White);
    Pen^ pen = gcnew Pen(Color::Black, 1);
    g->DrawLine(pen, 10, 10, 30, 50); // of course values may change
}
```

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To show the drawing immediately, refresh an object which drawing is created on. For example, if drawing was created like `g = Graphics::FromImage(pictureBox1->Image);` use `pictureBox1->Refresh();`